# Change a color of EditText's controls in the selected state

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

In my app I get a color scheme for the app from the server. I update colors for all app views according to the server settings. My question is related to updating colors of EditText in the selected state:

[image]

I can change a background color of selection, using the `editText.setHighlightColor()` method, but can I somehow change a color of **blue drag views** at the left and right bottom corners? I can't change the color, using the `colorAccent` style attribute, as I get the color from the server at runtime. Can I change the drag views dynamically?

Comment: @primo, my question is related to the blue drag views at the bottom left and right corners, not to the highlight color

Comment: maybe you can use Android markdown library for your job... check that ...

Comment: Themes are immutable, you can not.

Comment: Try <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item> in theme style.. worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is full example, custom TextInputLayout colors:

in your custom `*.xml` file, check properties `style` and `android:theme`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/txtConfirmPassword"
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:hint="@string/confirm_password_hint"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        style="@style/TextInputEditTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:theme="@style/TextInputEditTextTheme" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

in your `themes.xml` file

```
<style name="TextInputEditTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_text</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputEditTextTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/gray2</item> <!-- background of selected text -->
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/main_text</item> <!-- cursor -->
</style>
```

you can custom `TextInputLayout`'s border, by adding this to `themes.xml`

```
    <style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_layout_tint</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">1dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">8dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">8dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">8dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">8dp</item>
</style>
```

file `@color/text_input_layout_tint`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/action_yes" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/stroke" />
</selector>
```